# Overwrite an existing file in S3 using S3DistCp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I am trying to use S3-Dist-Cp Command to write out a log file to my S3 Bucket from EMR cluster after daily run. If the file (with the same name) already exists in the S3 file, S3-Dist-Cp writes a new file with and appends a number to filename.

Is there a way I can overwrite the existing file in S3 using S3-Dist-Cp ( I don't see -overwrite Flag or -delete flag for S3DistCp Documentation from AWS) ?

Comment: Did you find a way to overwrite/delete the target folder before writing using s3DistCp